# Backward lookup in order_by

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is example model:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(SampleSet)
    type = models.IntegerField()
    code = models.IntegerField()

class SampleSet(models.Model):
    some_text = models.TextField()
```

Is there any ways to use backward lookups in order_by? Need to write method returned `SampleSet` queryset sorted by `laboratory` field in `Sample` with `type=0`

Something like:

```
SampleSet.objects.order_by('sample(type=0)__code')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter first before you order

```
SampleSet.objects.filter(sample__type=0).order_by('sample__code')
```

If you still need the all samples as well then I'd suspect you need to order by type first, then by code.

```
SampleSet.objects.order_by('sample__type', 'sample__code')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SampleSet.objects.filter(sample__type=0).order_by('sample__code')
```